# How to give an Access key to a button with image on it.? If we press ALT +S then not able fire the click event

Tags: c#, wpf

```
      <Button Margin="0,0,5,0" Cursor="Hand"
                            ToolTip="Search"  Command="{Binding SearchButton}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SaveButton,Path=IsEnabled,       
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                               <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand 
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="False"
                                        Command="{Binding SearchButton}"
                                    />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Label Visibility="Collapsed">_Search</Label>
                                            <Image Source="/CHKRevAcc;component/Images/search.png" />
                                       </Grid>
                                     </DataTemplate>
                                </Button.ContentTemplate> 
      </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **AccessText** element to wrap the text that should have the access key specified.

```
    <Button Margin="0,0,5,0" Cursor="Hand"
            ToolTip="Search"  Command="{Binding SearchButton}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SaveButton,Path=IsEnabled,       
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
             <cmd:EventToCommand 
                  PassEventArgsToCommand="False"
                  Command="{Binding SearchButton}"
             />
          </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <Button.ContentTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <AccessText Visibility="Collapsed">_Search</AccessText>
              <Image Source="/CHKRevAcc;component/Images/search.png" />
           </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
       </Button.ContentTemplate> 
    </Button>
```

If that doesn't work, then you may not want to set the visibility to collapsed. Instead, make it opaque and shorten the text to

```
<AccessText Opacity="0">_S</AccessText>
```

This way, the button will still process the text, but it will be invisible. Not sure if you'll need to take this last step though.

Comment: Thanks but if i have another dragpanel on top how can i prevent it from firing. like i opened another panel on top of it and Alt+s it still fires.

Comment: The only way I know to have it stop responding to ALT+S would be to disable the button, or it's container.